# WYSIWYG editor appends // in script tag

Tags: magento2

Currently I am working on **Magento 2**

So my Question is

**Why wysiwyg editor appends `//` in script tag? While saving CMS page or CMS block**

`//` are appended after script tag starts and before script tag close

it is continuously appending `//` while save page or block

- Is there any reason of it?
- If want to overcome that than how to do that?

**EXAMPLE**

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">
// <![CDATA[
// 
// 
// 
   require(['jquery'],function($){
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert("test")       
      });
   });          
// 
// 
// 
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: write here some example.

Comment: @SohelRana i just added example in my question